# Show that function is convex if other function is convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let C be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For any two points x and y in C, define the function $\phi: [\ 0,1 ]\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\phi(\lambda) = f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$. I have to show that if $\phi$ is convex for any pair of x and y points in C, then f is convex.

I began by assuming $\phi$ is convex and taking $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$, such that $\forall \mu \in (0,1)$

\begin{equation}
\phi(\mu \lambda_{1} + (1-\mu)\lambda_{2}) \leq \mu\phi(\lambda_{1}) + (1-\mu)\phi(\lambda_{2})
\end{equation}

Let $\alpha = \mu \lambda_{1} + (1-\mu)\lambda_{2}$, then

\begin{equation}
f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \leq \mu f(\lambda_{1} x + (1-\lambda_{1})y) + (1-\mu)f(\lambda_{2} x + (1-\lambda_{2})y)
\end{equation}

From here on I don't know how to proceed

PS: I think the statement is true, if it isn't then a counterexample will suffice

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)&=\phi(\lambda)=\phi(\lambda\cdot1+(1-\lambda)\cdot0)\\
&\leq\lambda(\phi(1)+(1-\lambda)\phi(0) \\
&=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)(f(y)
\end{aligned}$$